# Centroid of Volume bounded by a Line and a Parabola

Tags: integration

I was looking for the centroid of the solid generated by revolving about the indicated axis the area bounded by the curves $y^2 = 4ax$ and $y = mx$ about the line $x = 0$

My work:

[image]

I do know that the centroid of volume created is $V \bar y = \int y_c dV.$ After solving it for almost 30 minutes,  I got: $$V = \frac{32\pi a^3}{3m^4}$$, $$y_c = \sqrt{ax} - \frac{mx}{2}$$ and $$dV = (4\pi ax - \pi m^2x^2) dx$$

I ended up getting the answer $$\bar y = \frac{6}{5} + \frac{19a^2}{5m^2}$$, which is very far from the correct answer $\bar y = \frac{5a}{2m}$

my question is, how do you get the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that your volume is incorrect. In the first place, we can say that

$$
V=2\pi\int x\Delta y(x)~dx\\
\Delta y(x)= \sqrt{4ax}-mx\\
\text{or}\\
V=\pi\int \Delta(x^2(y))~dy\\
\Delta(x^2)=\left(\frac{y^2}{m^2}-\frac{y^4}{(4a)^2} \right)
$$

I used the integration over $y$ and found that for $y\in[0,4a/m]$

$$V=\frac{2}{15}\frac{(4a)^3}{m^5}\pi$$

Then following through with your suggestion for

$$Vy_c=\int_0^{4a/m} y~dV=\frac{1}{12}\frac{(4a)^4}{m^6}\pi$$

There follows

$$y_c=\frac{5a}{2m}$$

as required. I have verified these results for arbitrary values of $a$ and $m$.

Also, notice that all of the quantities have dimensions. It must be that $a$ has the dimensions of *length* and $m$ is dimensionless. Accordingly, $V$ has dimensions of length cubed, while the centroid has dimensions of length.

Comment: Woah! thanks man!